# Are the reads from S3 truly parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parallel-processing, computer-science, disk

Consider a large file uploaded on S3 (without multi part upload). In many articles like [this](https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/parallelize-processing-a-large-aws-s3-file-8eh), I see that programs/applications can parallelly read from a single file on S3

Are the reads from S3 truly parallel? I ask this because given there is only one head in a hard disk, how can the head parallelly seek different chunks parallelly and transfer them?

Extending this question on a local machine, can a file stored on a single hard disk be read parallelly in chunks?

Comment: Are you sure that rotating hard disk read heads are the bottleneck on S3?

Comment: Also, what does "true parallel" mean? Even if it was limited by a single read head, could two simultaneous processes receive blocks of the same file in turn, e.g. A1, B1, A2, B2 etc., and might that still be faster than transferring the entire file to just one process? Yes, that's entirely possible and would count as parallelism.

Comment: "only one head in a hard disk" The days of one read head in a hard drive are long gone.  Not that it remotely matters, since this all presupposes the bottleneck in S3 is the speed of a single drive somewhere storing the only copy of data, and that there exists no cache at all anywhere along the layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are stored on **multiple devices in each data center** and are replicated across **multiple data centers**. An object is certainly *not* stored on a single hard disk.

It does not matter whether multiple users are accessing the same file or different files. Each disk block can be served from **multiple S3 servers from multiple storage devices**.

This is different to **your own computer** where you only have 'one copy' of a file. While a NAS device stores multiple copies of data, there is only a single NAS and a single network connection between your computer and a NAS, so it isn't truly parallel.

Comment: It would be fair to start with **"No, it is never true-[PARALLEL], it is a just-[CONCURRENT] distributed-storage** with several times replicated physical storage of data and with DataCenter orchestrated latency-masking (which can save hefty part of the still slow phys.storage right by coordinated distributed reads of small parts, re-arranged to receiving processes as if these were pure-[SERIAL] reads from some "accelerated" device )" and also add **"this trick can help only during periods of low coincidence of D/C read-requests + blocks once coordination fails to find "free" replica-reader"**?